# Set block in other block - doesn't work

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, xml, store-view

I have problem with adding block inside another block..

my code:

```
 <reference name="content">
        <block type="checkout/onepage_login" template="opc/login.phtml" >
            <block type="webformat_loginwithpaypal/checkout_onepage_login_button" name="loginwithpaypal.checkout.onepage.login.button" />
        </block>
    </reference>
```

Then when i call `$this->getChildHtml();` in login.phtml I do not see this view.

Any help ?

Comment: try adding `as="loginwithpaypal.button"` on the inner block.

Comment: that not work ;(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to call this block: `name="loginwithpaypal.checkout.onepage.login.button"`in login.phtml, you have to do these changes:

**local.xml:**

```
<customer_account_login>
   <reference name="root">
      <block type="checkout/onepage_login" template="opc/login.phtml">
         <block type="webformat_loginwithpaypal/checkout_onepage_login_button" name="loginwithpaypal.checkout.onepage.login.button" template="path/to/template.phtml"/>
      </block>
   </reference>
</customer_account_login>
```

Then in your login.phtml, you call it like this:

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('loginwithpaypal.checkout.onepage.login.button'); ?>
```

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
$this->getChildHtml();
```

with

```
$this->getChildHtml(loginwithpaypal.checkout.onepage.login.button);
```

Comment: That's doesn't work for me  ;/

Comment: It sounds like there is another problem, have you added any logic to render the code? If not you may need to specify a template for `webformat_loginwithpaypal/checkout_onepage_login_button`

Answer (score 0):

How did you call the `$this->getChildHtml()` method?. Into the login.phtml file you must do `echo`:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('loginwithpaypal.checkout.onepage.login.button') ?>
```

Also, did you already specify the template path ?, if you did not set it in the Block then you can add `template="path/to/button.phtml"`:

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="checkout/onepage_login" template="opc/login.phtml" >
        <block type="webformat_loginwithpaypal/checkout_onepage_login_button" name="loginwithpaypal.checkout.onepage.login.button" template="path/to/button.phtml" />
    </block>
</reference>
```

If it does not work, could you give more details of your code?